# Set the default value of an optional 'List(Of t)' parameter to an empty list?

Tags: vb.net, optional-parameters, empty-list

In this example, I can't figure out how to set the optional parameter `c` to an empty `List(Of thing)`:

```
Sub abcd(a as something, b as something, optional c as List(Of thing) = ?? )
    ' *stuff*
End Sub
```

I considered setting `c` to `null`, but that seems like a bad thing to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't. Optional values have to be compile-time constants. The only compile-time constant you can assign to `List(Of T)` is `Nothing`.

What you *can* do is overload that method with one that omits the `List(Of T)`parameter. This overload can then pass an empty `List(Of T)` to the original method:

```
Sub abcd(a as something, b as something)
    abcd(a, b, New List(Of T)())
End Sub

Sub abcd(a as something, b as something, c as list(of thing))
    doStuff()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I appreciate this is an old question (and shame on me for breaching etiquette in replying) but...

I had exactly the same issue today. It was resolved by passing an object...

```
Sub abcd(a as something, b as something, optional c as Object = Nothing )
    Dim lstC as new List(Of thing)
    If Not IsNothing(c) then
        lstC = c
    End IF
    ' Then in your code you just have to see if lstC.Count > 0
    ' *stuff*
End Sub
```